# Add a php into a iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I need to add output of a .php file into an iframe. Is this possible?

```
if($_GET['someAction']=="somePage"){
    require_once("somePage.php");
}
```

How do I dump the output of above code into an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I dump the output of above code into an iframe?

By putting it in an `<iframe>` element instead of requiring it server-side via `require`.

```
if($_GET['someAction']=="somePage") {
    echo '<iframe src="somePage.php"></iframe>';
}
```

Comment: I'm not good in php. How ever it shows some errors of "somePage.php" inside the iframe. And I need to add that php file only for one time. So I added "require_once()" and it worked for me. Now need it within that iframe. Please if you can understand tell me something

Comment: Why do you want to do this in an iframe? Can't help you without more context.

Comment: I want to load couple of pages. So I thought to use iframe.

Comment: If you're going to load a page into an iframe, it should be a *page*, starting with a doctype and an `<html>` root element. Are your pages set up this way? If so, the code posted should work. Without seeing error messages, I can't tell you why it wouldn't. Please edit any errors you're receiving into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert this code directly into your html:

```
<?php if($_GET['someAction']=="somePage"){ ?>
 <iframe src="somePage.php"></iframe>
<?php } ?>
```